# machine uptime is not consistent with last command

Tags: rhel, kernel, reboot, last, uptime

we have 3 rhel servers version 7.6 ( part of cluster with 8 machines )

on rhel server 1 machine uptime is

```
uptime
 10:25:51 up 23:48,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.09, 0.13
```

on rhel server 2 machine uptime is

```
 uptime
 10:26:19 up 20:13,  1 user,  load average: 27.86, 20.08, 10.14
```

on rhel server 3 machine uptime is

```
 uptime
 10:26:53 up 22:44,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.12, 0.14
```

but from `last` command ( `last | grep reboot | head -1` ) we can see that last reboot time is equal as

on rhel server 1 machine uptime is

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.el7.x Sat Jan 30 09:46 - 10:27 (1+00:41)
```

on rhel server 2 machine uptime is

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.el7.x Sat Jan 30 09:46 - 10:28 (1+00:41)
```

on rhel server 3 machine uptime is

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.el7.x Sat Jan 30 09:45 - 10:29 (1+00:43)
```

so how we can explain this strange behavior ?

how it can be that server reboot is the same but uptime time is not?

example

here the `uptime -s` of all 8 machines

```
13:41:52
10:37:32
14:21:56
10:09:27
14:13:17
11:42:23
10:22:40
13:46:41
```

while from `last` command *reboot* time is equal to all them

Comment: Please add the output of `uptime -s` which is easier to compare.

Comment: see the update above

Comment: Interesting, on Debian `uptime -s` prints the date in the `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: Do all the servers have the same date/time?